# htaccess redirect for redirecting all url with page to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need advise on to 301 permanent redirect using htaccess all pages having ?page=9 with index.php

Can anyone guide on how to achieve desired

**For example -1**

```
http://www.example.com/?page=9&option=com_news&view=list&Itemid=100&limitstart=840
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/index.php&option=com_news&view=list&Itemid=100&limitstart=840
```

**or say for example 2**

```
http://www.example.com/?page=17&option=com_news&view=list&Itemid=100
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/index.php&option=com_news&view=list&Itemid=100
```

**Edit**
Used

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?page=.+&(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php&%1? [L,R=301]
```

But it dint worked as output is

```
http://www.example.com/index.php&limitstart=840
```

Comment: You just wanna remove page?

Comment: yes remove ?page and add index.php against it

Comment: `index.php` is implicit (assuming your `DirectoryIndex` is set up for it) - there's no practical difference between `/?something=something` and `/index.php?something=something`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you actually want `/index.php?option=...` rather than `/index.php&option=...` - just matching on the querystring:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=[^&]+&(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /index.php?%1 [L,R,QSD]
```

However if you really **do** want `/index.php&option=...` replace the RewriteRule with:

```
RewriteRule .* /index.php&%1 [L,R,QSD]
```

*Note: either way, this may not work as expected if `page` is not the first paramter*

---

If your Apache version is older than 2.4 replace the RewriteRule with:

```
RewriteRule .* /index.php?%1? [L,R]
```

The `[QSD]` flag was only introduced with 2.4 - *shouldn't* be necessary anyway since the entire querystring is being matched.

Comment: can i use - 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=[^&]+&(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /index.php?%1 [L,R=301]

Comment: There's no difference between `R` and `R=301` in the flags since the default redirect is 301... that should work; `QSD` should just discard any additional querystrings from the rewritten URL - since you're matching the whole thing it shouldn't be necessary so yeah, you can leave it off. I'm just paranoid about infinitely recursive loops when doing querystring rewrites.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?page=.+&(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php&%1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Technically that's what's requested but I suspect you're about to get a *didn't work* comment because the querystring is being started with `&`

Comment: Thanks but it dint worked - output is http://www.example.com/index.php&limitstart=840

Comment: @Ruchika - no but you could try `\?page=.+?&(.+)\sHTTP` instead, adding `?` after the `+` changes it to a non-greedy match... though I thought Apache mod_rewrite was non-greedy by default.